# Does a content page always have a title area at the top?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a content page like this:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="phrasesStackLayout">
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Inside this I add a tabbed page.

At the top of the content page there is a title area.  Is there a way I can have this not appear. I don't want to have a title and the top of the page is wasted.

Here's what I have now:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var phrasesPage = new NavigationPage(new PhrasesPage())
    {
        Title = "Pause",
        Icon = "pause.png",

    };

    ...
}

public partial class PhrasesPage : ContentPage
{
    public PhrasesFrame phrasesFrame;

    public PhrasesPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HasNavigationBar = "False"; // Doesn't work
        AS.phrasesPage = this;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code seems incomplete, but you must do something like this:

```
public partial class PhrasesPage : ContentPage
{
    public PhrasesFrame phrasesFrame;

    public PhrasesPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); 
        AS.phrasesPage = this;
    }

    (...)

}
```

Comment: I tried what you said and have added an example in the question.  It doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Diego, rather than snippets can you copy paste the code I have and modify that as your answer. I think that would be more clear for me and others. Thanks

Comment: Sure! I'm sorry for that.

Comment: It works.  Thanks very much.  BTW if you are interested in building up more points there are some Xamarin questions with big bounties from me an my work mate. One has a 500 point bounty. Have a good day.